# How can I write the solving steps of a system of equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I'm trying to do the following in LaTeX:

[image: My equation system on paper]

The box at the end doesn't have to be there. I've tried using `cases`, from the amsmath package, but it doesn't align correctly with the equations on top, nor is the formatting very pretty:

[image: latex equation]

This is the code I used:

```
\begin{align*}
    \sum \vec{F} &= ma \\
    \vec{R_n} + \vec{Fg} + \vec{F_a} &= ma \\

    \begin{cases}
        \vec{F_a} &= ma_c\\
        \vec{R_n} - \vec{F_g} &= 0
    \end{cases}  

    \begin{cases}
        uR_n &= m\frac{v^2}{r}\\
        R_n &= mg
    \end{cases}  

    \begin{cases}
        ug &= \frac{v^2}{r}\\
        R_n &= mg
    \end{cases}  

    \begin{cases}
        \sqrt{ugr} &= v\\
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
```

Thanks in advance, I'm  a LaTeX beginner :)

Comment: When I saw this question in the Hot Network Questions, I was half-expecting to find an answer with a computer algebra system in TeX that will solve the equations by itself, *then* typeset the steps it took :-D

Comment: That would've been awesome indeed, haha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some improvements with `mathtools` and `esvect` (for nicer-looking arrow tips), and a slightly different layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, esvect}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
                  & \mkern1.5mu \sum \vv{F} = ma \Leftrightarrow\vv*{R}{n} + \vv*{F}{g} + \vv*{F}{a} = ma \\
  \Leftrightarrow & \begin{dcases}
  \vv{F_a} = ma_c\\
  \vv*{R}{n} - \vv*{F}{g} = 0
  \end{dcases}
  %
  \Leftrightarrow \begin{dcases}
  uR_n = m\frac{v^2}{r}\\
  R_n = mg
  \end{dcases}
  %
  \Leftrightarrow \begin{dcases}
  ug = \frac{v^2}{r}\\
  R_n = mg
  \end{dcases}\\
  \Leftrightarrow & \hspace*{\fboxsep} \boxed{\sqrt{ugr} = v}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm curious, why do you use literal $\Sigma$ and $\surd$ characters in the source? Are there advantages?

Comment: @andrepd: Actually, I don't use them in the source (LaTeX wouldn't compile them). Simply, my editor is configured to `display` a number of maths symbols and Greek letters, but saves them as latex commands. I shouldn't have posted the display, but  the saved file, and I forgot to check. I'll fix that in a moment. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: Is it possible for LaTex to detect where margins are, and adjust the cases equations accordingly? With a longer system, things get a bit... [badly formatted](http://i.imgur.com/a3iw0CP.jpg) (the big lines are the margins). And using `//`in the third case [doesn't seem to help either :(](http://i.imgur.com/BYTy3N9.jpg). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The following should be a good starting point. Please observe removing most of your ampersands. Id you really need iff as in the picture, I can corect my example, but this version seems to be more standard one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
   & \sum \vec{F} = ma \\
  &\iff  \vec{R_n} + \vec{Fg} + \vec{F_a} = ma \\
   &\iff    \begin{cases}
        \vec{F_a} = ma_c\\
        \vec{R_n} - \vec{F_g} = 0
    \end{cases}  
%
  \iff  \begin{cases}
        uR_n = m\frac{v^2}{r}\\
        R_n = mg
    \end{cases}  
%
   \iff \begin{cases}
        ug = \frac{v^2}{r}\\
        R_n = mg
    \end{cases}  
%
   \iff \begin{cases}
        \boxed{\sqrt{ugr} = v}\\
        \strut
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   & \sum \vec{F} = ma \\
\Leftrightarrow{}
   & \vec{R_n} + \vec{Fg} + \vec{F_a} = ma \\
\Leftrightarrow{}
   & \begin{cases}
        \vec{F_a} &= ma_c\\
        \vec{R_n} - \vec{F_g} &= 0
    \end{cases}  
\Leftrightarrow
    \begin{cases}
        uR_n &= m\frac{v^2}{r}\\
        R_n &= mg
    \end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow
    \begin{cases}
        ug &= \frac{v^2}{r}\\
        R_n &= mg
    \end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow
    \begin{cases}
        \sqrt{ugr} &= v\\
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the difference between using `Leftrightarrow{}` and `Leftrightarrow`?

Comment: @Pada Try both versions and observe the spacing. The braces `{}` simulate an operand for the relation symbol `\Leftrightarrow`, which adds an appropriate space. Without the braces there is no operand, so the aligned stuff follows immediately after the arrow.

Comment: I see, it's subtle but it is indeed there.